# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:942 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module 'express' Require stack:

Tags: node.js, express, npm, node-modules, loader

I am working on running my express server with the command npm start. I am receiving: ```node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:942
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'express'
Require stack: ```.

I currently do not have node modules and also receive errors when I type the command npm install. I've deleted node modules outside of the current directory, upgraded the version, & have been googling answers. I would appreciate the help. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You need to install express as the error is showing that express is missing. The command for that shall be `npm install express --save`. You have also mentioned that you are receiving error upon running `npm install` .

**Updated**

Remove bycrypt-nodejs from your package.json file as it is deprecated. Then run `npm install`. If you need bycrypt you can run `npm install bcrypt` or `npm install bcryptjs` which suits your project better. Afterwards run `npm install express --save`. Hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the response! When I type npm install express --save, I receive  this error:                                                                                                                npm WARN deprecated bcrypt-nodejs@0.0.3: bcrypt-nodejs is no longer actively maintained. Please use bcrypt or bcryptjs. See https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/bcrypt-vs-brypt.js to learn more about these two options
npm ERR! code 1

Comment: You are welcome. As my understanding goes bcrypt-nodejs is creating the problem. So my suggestion is,  remove bycrpyt-nodejs from you dependencies that is from the package.json file and try to run npm install. It should work. And according to the documentation npm install bcrypt should be a replacement from bycrpt-nodejs. After wards you may run the installation for express.

Comment: @AndreaEverett i have updated my answer. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are in the wrong folder or your file name is wrong. Try `ls` to see if all your necessary packages are there. If not go to the right folder and type `npm i` in the terminal. This should solve the issue of any missing packages. Then use `npm run start`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still getting error

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```